# step by step execution

Tags: linux

how to perform step by step execution in Linux,i want to see the content of the used variables the address and the value that the pointers are holding

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Compile your program by giving `-g` flag. This will create the debugging information (symbols) for your program.

```
gcc -g -o foo foo.c
```

Then run the program with a debugger of your choice. Here is an example using `gdb`

```
# gdb foo
# b main  --> this will set the break point at main function.
# r       --> start running your program. If you want to pass some argument, use: r <args>
# n       --> to goto next line of execution
# print <var> --> to print variable value
# help  --> for list of supported commands.
```